# Does Visiblity Timeout > Message Retention Period guarantee only once delivery in Standard SQS queues?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am building a SQS -> Lambda trigger.
The Lambda makes some API calls and it should be triggered only once per message sent to the queue even if the Lambda fails. When I set up the queue with the default config, lambda was getting triggered multiple times for a single message when the lambda fails

Since the queue deletes the message when the message retention period expires, I have set the Visiblity Timeout greater than Message Retention Period so that the message comes to the queue, triggers the lambda and gets deleted automatically by the queue before it becomes visible again

So far, this seems to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Please note **SQS** doesn't delete the message from the message. The message processing application need to delete the message when it processes within the visibility timeout. Failing to do so, will put the message back on the queue.

Also Standard SQS doesn't guarantee only once delivery.

The best practice is to create a Dead Letter Queue If the processing of the message fails multiple times.

**Visibility timeout:** Should be between 0 seconds and 12 hours (default: 30 seconds).

> Visibility timeout sets the length of time that a message received from a queue (by one consumer) will not be visible to the other message consumers.
> The visibility timeout begins when Amazon SQS returns a message. If the consumer fails to process and delete the message before the visibility timeout expires, the message becomes visible to other consumers. If a message must be received only once, your consumer must delete it within the duration of the visibility timeout.
> The default visibility timeout setting is 30 seconds. This setting applies to all messages in the queue. Typically, you should set the visibility timeout to the maximum time that it takes your application to process and delete a message from the queue.

**Message retention period:** Should be between 1 minute and 14 days (default: 4 days).

> The message retention period is the amount of time that Amazon SQS retains a message that does not get deleted. Amazon SQS automatically deletes messages that have been in a queue for more than the maximum message retention period. The default retention period is 4 days. The retention period has a range of 60 seconds to 1,209,600 seconds (14 days).
> The expiration of a message is always based on its original enqueue timestamp. When a message is moved to a dead-letter queue, the enqueue timestamp remains unchanged. For example, if a message spends 1 day in the original queue before being moved to a dead-letter queue, and the retention period of the dead-letter queue is set to 4 days, the message is deleted from the dead-letter queue after 3 days. For this reason, we recommend that you always set the retention period of a dead-letter queue to be longer than the retention period of the original queue.

Comment: The OP uses lambda, so lambda does remove the messages automatically after processing. So the processing application does not have to do it.

Comment: What is OP....?

Comment: @Riz Original Poster

Comment: @sri SQS does delete the message once the Message Retention Period of a particular message expires

Comment: @Marcin In my case I am letting the queue auto delete the messages once the Message Retention Period of a particular message expires. The lambda doesn't delete messages